# warning regarding the cell of UITableviewcell

Tags: iphone

cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search_up.png"];

whenever i'm  writing  this  statement i get  warning  like 
deprecated

if i use 
cell.textLabel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search_up.png"];
i   got error

how  to remove  this warning or  error

Comment: If only there were documentation of these deprecated properties somewhere... http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"search_up.png"]];
```

Comment: +1. Or, cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""search_up.png"];